# What happens if I free Jona Sederis?

Tags: mass-effect-3

During Aria's side missions to unite the gangs, you're told to free Jona Sederis so that Aria will gain the allegiance of the Eclipse mercs.

In my previous playthrough, I instead told Sayn to take over the Eclipse, as he seemed like less of a psycho killer.

This time around though, I'm playing a renegade Shepard, and I'm considering freeing Jona.

Will she kill anyone important to me? Will the Eclipse be more powerful as a result? What exactly happens if I free her?

Comment: If you're playing on PC, the choice is more "Free Sederis" or "Glitched Mission"

Comment: @SteveV. I am playing on PC and it was totally cool with me not freeing Sederis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Eclipse War Asset modifier is the same +50 regardless of how you resolve the situation. The only difference is the reputation you gain.

Release Sederis = +5 Renegade
Convince Sayn to take over = +2 Paragon
Convince Sayn to kill Sederis after she is released = none

Comment: Even I'm writing this more than two years after your answer, I was playing ME3 again and I've got different results while full Renegade. If releasing Jona Sederis Shepard receives +7 Renegade Points, some credits and Terminus Fleet War Asset. If Shepard convinces Sayn to take over Eclipse he/she receives +2 Renegade points after talk to Bailey through the console and other +2 Renegade Points after taking the Renegade path when he / she supports Jona's murder.

Answer (score 1):

Sayn will choose to kill Sederis regardless if you free her or leave her in jail.

Answer (score 1):

> Sayn (her second-in-command) will kill her and assume her place.

It's a matter of Paragon/Renegade choice really, it has no other influence on the game.